# What to do if accuracy is still improving but the epochs end?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

When I was running my model for 3 hours for 50 epochs and my accuracy was 65% and improving. Can I resume the model training? Or do I have to run the model again for greater number of epochs?

I really dont want to run the model again so is there any way I can avoid this and resume the training where it stopped?

Comment: if i was getting only 65% accuracy after 50 epochs, i might start feature engineering

Comment: I'm doing deep learning on text classification. Already did processing of input data.

Comment: If you have not closed your script (or if you have saved your model), you can simply use more `model.fit` commands to continue training from the last executed epoch.

Comment: I have not closed the scripy and I have also saved my model. Do I just continue with model.fit ? Like the very next line?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the model and load it again and if necessary u can further train the loaded model. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I copy-paste for every project in which I need to resume training:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

weights_path = Path('C:/code/.../file.h5')
if weights_path.exists():
    print('Loading weights from %s...' % weights_path)
    model.load_weights(str(weights_path))

cb_best = ModelCheckpoint(
    str(weights_path),
    monitor = 'val_loss',
    verbose = 1,
    save_weights_only = True,
    save_best_only = True,
    mode = 'min')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 10, callbacks = [cb_best], verbose = 1)
```

So if you restart the training script it will resume where it left off.